# find all functions imported using "from something import * "

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to find everything imported using the asterisk syntax:

```
from something import *
```

Ideally, I would think there is a way to find any (class I presume) in a script that was imported using the asterisk syntax. Maybe using the **ast** module, I am not sure.

Thus for the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from Modules.SelectionWindow import SelectionWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    data = open("../assets/version.txt" , "r").read()
    window.state("zoomed")
    window.title("Something here | " + data)
    window.iconbitmap("../assets/images/Icon.ico")
    app = SelectionWindow(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

We should be able to select the following:
**TK()**

Comment: I don't see any other way except for investigating `globals()`. But, why do you want to do that? `import *` is an anti-pattern and should be avoided (even if some library's documentation suggests it or says that "it's ok")

Comment: Do you want everything exported by the module, or just the exported names that you *use* elsewhere?

Comment: @chepner I want anything exported and used in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dir()`, you will see both, methods and attributes:

```
import tkinter
dir(tkinter)
```

Output:

```
['ACTIVE',
 'ALL',
 'ANCHOR',
 'ARC',
 'BASELINE',
 'BEVEL',
 'BOTH',
 'BOTTOM',
 'BROWSE',
 'BUTT',
 'BaseWidget',
 'BitmapImage',
 'BooleanVar'
...
```

Comment: but I don't think that will give me the imports that are in the script. It'll just give all the attributes of tkinter.

Comment: @AkbarHussein but when you use the star you bring everything, methods and attributes

Comment: even so; the only thing used in the script at the question is TK(). Thus I don't need all the list given by dir().

Comment: Do the `import something` in _addition_ to you `from something import *`. Then, `dir(something)` tells you what you got. It costs very little and does no harm.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
before = globals().copy()
from tkinter import *
after = globals().copy()
imported = {}
for key in after.keys():
  if key not in before.keys() and key != "before":
    imported[key] = after[key]

print(imported)
```

this gives you anything that was imported by `from tkinter import *`

Comment: I would like to confirm that: after.copy().keys() isn't a mistake?

Comment: yeah, it is. it's just dictionaries behaving strangely, I put it there and forgot about it. it doesn't affect the result, however.

Comment: it should be fixed now

Comment: your answer might work, but it seems I will have to modify every file; thus inserting the before and after statement after every line. But what if we have more than one of the (form something import *) syntax? What if we want to do for a collection of files?

Comment: you can use the help of the IDE you're using. there is in every IDE (at least the one I worked with) such utility u just need to make sure "Change in All Files" option or something (it changes from IDE to the other) is checked.

Answer (score -1):

Its a bit of a kludge, but I have done this in the past:

1. Find and replace all star imports with regular imports
2. Run a linter to catch all your "undefined variable" errors. There are options in pylint to only lint for a particular error

If you ran the linter prior to this change and you got no undefined variable error, you now have a list of all identifiers relying on * imports.